# Does atom editor has a syntax theme like the one in React Native's website?

Tags: react-native, themes, atom-editor

keywords like `class, import, let, return` are in blue, strings are in green and common words are in dark.
like this one:
[color in docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/state.html)

Does Atom has a syntax theme like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) plugin for Atom. It is from Facebook and specifically designed for React-Native development. In addition to syntax highlighting itll give you access to all sorts of handy dev tools.

[Here are the docs](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/) for both installing Nuclide on its own or inside of Atom.

Comment: Nuclide has been added to Atom,  we just don't like the syntax color scheme provided. Currently we are using Solarized Light and try to find another one~ And Thanks Nitpick :)

Comment: Ahh okay I gotcha. If noone comes up with a specific suggestion you can always try searching [atom's theme page](https://atom.io/themes) for a solution. I took a quick glance and it looks like [this theme](https://atom.io/themes/atom-light-simple-syntax) and [this theme](https://atom.io/themes/dead-simple-light-syntax) are close to what you want. Also, if you could [make your own atom theme](http://blog.gaku.net/create-a-custom-syntax-highlighting-with-atom-editor/) if you are dead set on an exact match. Best of luck!

Comment: We will using the links provided, that's we want. Thanks Nitpick~

Comment: How are you not blinded by Solarized Light? o.O. nuclide looks decent, but I'll probably have to customize a dark theme to my liking. Seti is close, but it would be much nicer if the function params are the same color when used in the function block as they are in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

nuclide is one of the most popular one and very useful, easy to debug.  there is another one that is called "Deco". this is also very popular too.

https://www.decosoftware.com

Comment: Heard that before, but as our company is stingy we are still using desktop PC with Windows7 and 8g memory as you guys did years ago. [doge]